# $(this) is causing e is undefined error

Tags: jquery

I found lots of people with similar errors but none being caused by $('this'). I did a tutorial and it worked fine, now I am trying to do one on my own and I get the e is not defined error when ever this is called.

I really don't know what question to ask, I'm just stumped.

Please forgive me if I screw up this code block.

```
$(function () {

    var nav = $('#nav'); //capture navigation call
    nav.children('li').addClass('navList'); //groups children (not grandchildren) and applies a class for easier use later

    $('.navList').each(function () { //.each is like for loop but with functions
        var that = $(this), //captures this call
            subMenu = that.find('ul') //groups sub menu items
            ;

        that.bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
            //console.log("that");
            subMenu.show().css();

        })
            .bind('mouseleave', function (e) {
            subMenu.hide();
        });
    });
});
```

HTML-not putting whole thing since it's the schools and I'm not sure how they feel about that. but here is the relevant part.

```
     <ul id="nav" class="cf">
        <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AJAX</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/">screencasts</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">AJAX</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/">projects</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: well... I got it in a block but it's formatting got all screwy.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LuQES/1/

Comment: but it can be simplified to http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LuQES/2/

Comment: there's no any use of `e` in this code, and there's no any element with class named `navList`

Comment: if I take the e out, it still gives e not defined error. That was the first thing I tried because I had no idea why it was there to start with.

Comment: @user3066791 the error is obviously coming from somewhere else.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LuQES/5/

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE! it is working now. Arun, I really like your reduced one but it bypassed some of the requirements. I saved it in my notes.... It seems I can't up vote comments. must be too new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subMenu.show().css();` is causing problems. The call to css() is unnecessary here.
It should be

```
        that.bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
            //console.log("that");
            subMenu.show();

        })
        .bind('mouseleave', function (e) {
            subMenu.hide();
        });
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/TsdRF/1/

Comment: Awsome man, that worked perfect. Of course I feel stupid now, but I've been feeling that frequently since I started learning this stuff.